# How to differentiate between the author and a language editor?

Tags: publications, translations

I will translate a LaTeX document from English to Greek. How should I write who is the author and who does the language editing?

This is my first time doing a translation and publishing it in a scientific journal.

I mean, is something like this a good template?

\documentclass{article}
\title{}
\author{\thanks{%
Translator of this article: }
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}

or do I have to write it in a different way?

Comment: Note that you need permission of any copyright holder (most places) to publish a translation.

Comment: What do you mean "how should (you) write"?

Comment: Maybe like this? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/270283/128923

Comment: Have you talked to the journal about your plans? They probably have guidelines for such things. Further, getting some buy-in from a journal before spending the time doing a translation would probably be a good idea.

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE! I am not sure you will get a good answer for such a technical question on this site. You should probably check the LaTeX Stack Exchange. You can start there with a search on "translator"-related questions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=translator.

Answer (score 0):

Publishing a translated article in a scientific journal is somewhat rare, especially if the original article is written in English, the lingua franca of much of science. Yours seems to be a rare case.  With machine translations getting better, the need for human translations is getting smaller, so that there is not a lot of precedence. Often, the translator does not appear (other than maybe in a foot-note). Some learned societies (American Meteorological Society, American Mathematical Society) publish translations of journals and articles from Russian and a few other languages. In this case, the translators are paid and their names do not appear. For books, the translator appears on the title page and is usually given in a complete citation. In the case of poetic works or classical literature, the translator becomes more important and is typically given. (Arno Schmidt's translation of English literature into German are read by Germans that are quite capable of reading the original because of the quality of the translation, which might even be seen as an enhancement of the original.) This is because translation has then many more artistic components than for a scientific article, which is supposed to be written in a bland language that demands less of a translator.

In short: There is precedence for leaving out the name of the translator as well for including the information on the translator. However, the name of the translator is -- as a rule -- not displayed prominently.

The rights-holder of the article (the author or the journal / conference / editor) might also have some ideas and some style guidelines. You probably should pose this question to them.